# javascript if negative condition not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to calculate elapsed hours between two times. When calculating PM to AM it will give me a negative result so I need to add 12 hours to the negative number for correct elapsed time. For this I have to add the condition `if ($some_result < 0)`. It works in php but not js, I can't figure out why

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wH7sC/1/

```
function calculateTime() { //gets time elapsed between 2 time marks

            var valuestart = $("select[name='timestart']").val();
            var valuestop = $("select[name='timestop']").val();

             //create date format          
             var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart).getHours();
             var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop).getHours();

             var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;      

              if ( hourDiff < 0 ) { //this is not working
                 hourDiff += 12;
             }

             return hourDiff;

}



//prepare function on load
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(calculateTime);
    calculateTime();
});



//execute function when changing select options
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        $( "#result" ).val( calculateTime() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the `if` statement failing. You need you add 24, not 12:

http://jsfiddle.net/sparebyte/wH7sC/2/

I recommend installing Chrome, Firefox, or IE9, opening the javascript developer console and making use of the `console.log(...)` function. I don't recommend using IE9, its output leaves me wanting.

Comment: Great that works! hmmm why does it work with 12 not 24 in php tho? Maybe because I'm using timestamp